# Swift Array of Realm object filter using another array

Tags: arrays, swift, realm

I am having problem with filtering realm object

This is my realm model object

```
class OutletDTO: Object, Mappable {
    var tags = List<OutletTag>()
}
class OutletTag: Object, Mappable {
    @objc dynamic var tagName: String?
}
```

the JSON will return list of Outlets and each of the outlet will have several tags

```
"tags": [
{
    "tagName": "A"
},
{
    "tagName": "B"
},
{
    "tagName": "C"
},
{
    "tagName": "D"
}
]
```

So I want to achieve filtering function based on the tag of the outlet

I have several buttons that will add Filter String to a [String]. 
What i am planning to do is, get my realm outlet object and then check whether the tags contain [FilterString]

My current code is

```
self.storeList = Array(realmOutletList).filter({ Array($0.tags).map({$0.tagName!}).sorted().joined().contains(self.filterArray.sorted().joined()) })
```

However, this code doesn't give me what I want.

For example

```
Outlet A, has tag : A, B, C 
Outlet B, has tag : B, C, D
Filter Array: A, D
Result: Outlet A and B // What i want is the result empty because no outlet has both A and D
```

Another example

```
Outlet A : A, B, C
Outlet B : A
Filter String: A, B
Expected Result: Outlet A // because A, B matches Outlet A. 
//Outlet B must be removed because there is no "B" inside the outlet B
Filter String: A 
Expected Result: Outlet A and Outlet B because they both have "A" inside
```

Can someone guide me please? If there is another approach that can achieve this is also welcomed, because I couldn't think of other approach to achieve this function.

Any help given is highly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You can make use of isSubSet method of Set.

> public func isSubset(of other: Set) -> Bool

I can explain this with your example

- **Get**

get your realm data

```
    let tagA = OutletTag(); tagA.tagName = "A"
    let tagB = OutletTag(); tagB.tagName = "B"
    let tagC = OutletTag(); tagC.tagName = "C"
    let tagD = OutletTag(); tagD.tagName = "D"

    let outlet1 = OutletDTO(); outlet1.tags.append(objectsIn: [tagA,tagB,tagC])
    let outlet2 = OutletDTO(); outlet2.tags.append(objectsIn: [tagA,tagC])


    do {
        try self.realm.write {
            self.realm.add([outlet1,outlet2])
        }
    } catch  {
        print("Error saving category \(error)")
    }

    let outlets = self.realm.objects(OutletDTO.self)

    let filterTag1 = OutletTag(); filterTag1.tagName = "A"
    let filterTag2 = OutletTag(); filterTag2.tagName = "B"

    let filterTags = [filterTag1,
                      filterTag2]
```

- **Convert**

convert your filterTags form List in to Set of String.

```
    let filterTagStrings = [filterTag1,
                      filterTag2].map({ (tag) -> String in
                        return tag.tagName ?? ""
                      })
    let setFilterTagStrings = Set(filterTagStrings)
```

- **Filter**

Filter List with Tags

```
    var filteredOutlets = [OutletDTO]()
    for outlet in outlets {

        let outletTagStrings:[String] = outlet.tags.map({ (tag) -> String in
            return tag.tagName ?? ""
        })
        let setOutletTagStrings = Set(outletTagStrings)

        if setFilterTagStrings.isSubset(of:setOutletTagStrings) {
            filteredOutlets.append(outlet)
        }
    }

    //Out put
    print(filteredOutlets)
```